# How do I make a simple HTML checkbox into a bool on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, checkbox, boolean

Model Code:

```
class Task(db.Model):
    complete = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="complete" value="True" />
```

Database:

```
task = Task()
task.complete = self.request.get('complete')
task.put()
```

This returns an error:

BadValueError: Property complete must be a bool

How should this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since unchecked checkboxes are not sent as a parameter...

```
task.complete = self.request.get('complete') != ''
```

Comment: Hey I guess I just have been refreshing the page too often, but I have seen all three of your edits.  All three worked for me and I appreciate your help.  Care to explain why this was better than the previously two working statements?  Thanks.  I'm new.

Comment: Mostly just it's the most straightforward. All 3 are perfectly fine options. `!= ''` would also be a viable option.

Comment: 'is not' tests for object identity. Python may make all empty strings the same object, but relying on that is probably a bad idea - I think using `!=` would be less prone to errors. :)

Comment: While I'm fairly sure every single serious Python interpreter out there will intern `''`, you're right that in theory it's a bad thing to rely on. Edited to `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type() funktion to check the tape of `self.request.get('complete')`
I would suggest, that `self.request.get('complete')` returns 'True' but as a **String** so you should convert it to boolean. [Here is a "list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715417/converting-from-a-string-to-boolean-in-python) of different methods