# Keeping track of processed lists

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have a workflow where I process lists, and keep track of which ones I've seen in a dictionary - because when I get to one that's been seen already, I can pass on it. The caveat is that two lists with the same elements ordered differently are considered duplicates. So to take a simple example of integer lists: `[3, 1, 5, 6]` and `[5, 3, 6, 1]` are equivalent.

How I've been doing this is, take `tuple(sorted(L))` and put that in my dictionary. So for the above example `seen` looks like:

```
seen = {..., (1, 3, 5, 6): 1, ...}
```

This has the nice advantage of being constant time lookup for each list I potentially need to process. The problem however is that in order to check if a given list is in `seen`, I have to do `tuple(sorted(L))` on it. And it turns out that for large amounts of data, this becomes prohibitive to the point of taking over 50% of the total time of my entire process.

I'd like to make use of `collections.Counter` somehow - because `Counter[3, 1, 5, 6]` and `Counter[5, 3, 6, 1]` would evaluate equal. But Counter objects can't be used as dict keys. How can I keep my dictionary lookup, but without doing the sorting operation indicated above? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: In looking at the suggestions to use `frozenset` I realized I left an important thing out, which is that elements can duplicate. So while the two lists above compare equal, `[3, 1, 5, 6]` and `[3, 3, 1, 5, 6, 6]` need to be seen as distinct. Since the `frozenset` operation would remove duplicates, it isn't an option here.

Comment: Not sure about this at all, but would `frozenset` reduce time consumption? Again, I have no idea about implementation details.

Comment: @j1-lee I suspect it's the sorting that ends up costing time, it's memory allocation, and an over-linear time complexity.

Comment: @Vatine Good to know! Thanks :)

Comment: How large are your lists and Counters?

Comment: I don't think setting tuples as dict keys is  a good idea. Maybe convert them into a string instead? That way, differently ordered tuple strings would be considered non-duplicates.

Comment: Why don't you add a flag to your dictionary to check if you've already processed your list or not? `{"list1": {"list": [1, 2, 3, 4], "seen": False}, "list2": {"list": [1, 2, 3, 4], "seen": True}}`

Comment: @j1-lee 's suggestion is good - instead of using `tuple(sorted(l))` as the key, use `frozenset(l)`.

Comment: That would work great but I neglected to mention an important requirement which I put in an edit to my post. ```frozenset``` would remove duplicates, which I need to keep. Sorry that I got wrapped up in writing the post and gave a poor example.

Comment: Looks like you overlooked my question: How large are your lists and Counters? That would be good to know in order to know what's the appropriate way forward. In particular, I asked that in order to know *how much* duplication you have. *That* you have duplication was already clear from you considering Counter instead of set.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Yes of course, that's a consideration. In the most extreme scenario I could have somewhere around 300,000 lists with anywhere from a few to many dozen elements. It's hard to be more precise because I don't know the full set at the start of execution. But, those are the order of magnitude numbers.

Comment: @PatJones That's helpful, and would be good to include in the question. Although still unclear how large the Counters are, i.e., how much duplication there is.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, frozenset is your best option:

```py
seen = set()

list_1, list_2, list_3 = [3, 1, 5, 6], [5, 3, 6, 1], [1, 2, 3]

print(frozenset(list_1) in seen)
seen.add(frozenset(list_1))
print(frozenset(list_1) in seen)
print(frozenset(list_2) in seen)
print(frozenset(list_3) in seen)
```

`frozenset` takes as an argument an iterable so instantiating the set would take O(n). Lookups have on average O(1), same as standard `set`, according to [this previous response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555214/set-vs-frozenset-performance). Either way, you would save the very expensive operation of sort which is O(n log n).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. That would work great but I neglected to mention an important requirement which I put in an edit to my post. ```frozenset``` would remove duplicates, which I need to keep.

Comment: That sounds wrong, you can't really consider the set size non-constant one time and then constant another time.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a lot of duplicates, then maybe use `frozenset` of `Counter` items?

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> frozenset(Counter([3, 3, 1, 5, 6, 6]).items())
frozenset({(1, 1), (3, 2), (6, 2), (5, 1)})
```

Or sorted tuples of `Counter` items:

```
>>> tuple(sorted(Counter([3, 3, 1, 5, 6, 6]).items()))
((1, 1), (3, 2), (5, 1), (6, 2))
```

Comment: Both of these actually increase my execution time substantially. I don't know enough about ```frozenset``` and ```Counter``` to say if that's surprising. As it turns out, my larger process has inefficiencies needing to be addressed, so what I'm trying to do here might be moot but is still an interesting question regardless.