# Reverse dictionary attributes set to ids?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, set

I have the following translation dictionary:

```
{0: {'a', 'b', 'c'},
1: {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
2: {'k', 'b', 'e', 'a', 'n'}}
```

And I want to 'reverse' it to be attributes to keys (keys here are a form of id).
Given a set of attributes, give me the relevant id (key).

For example, given `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` return `0`.

What is the best practice to do this? The attributes can come in different order that's why I am using sets.
Should I insert it into a dataframe (translation table)? Or there is another solution?

Comment: It depends on the amount of data. Up to e. g. 100k keys a simple approach with dict and sets should work.

Comment: You could look into `frozenset`. Since it is hashable, it  can be passed as a key to a reversed dict.

Comment: Use `{frosenset(v): k for k,v in data.items()}` (assuming the values are unique) then just convert to a frosenset when looking up a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use pandas. Here is a pure python solution.

You can reverse the dictionary to use a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=frozenset#frozenset) as key:

```
d = {0: {'a', 'b', 'c'},
     1: {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
     2: {'k', 'b', 'e', 'a', 'n'}}

rev_d = {frozenset(k): v for v,k in d.items()}

rev_d[frozenset({'a', 'c', 'b'})]
# 0
```

Comment: Great, I will check with Prof. Google what are the differences between set and frozen set.

Comment: @SteveS I provided a link to the doc ;) this is like a set but immutable

Comment: it is hashable because it is immutable ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, I have seen in the last answer in the following question Serge's comment saying that it's the hashable part that matters. Can you please explain why it's the immutable part? @mozway
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555214/set-vs-frozenset-performance

Comment: To make it clear, the **hashability** is was is needed to be used as key, but the fact that frozensets are hashable is because they are **immutable**, it wouldn't make much sense to store an object in a hash table (a dictionary) if the object can then change (which would change its hash). I hope this clarifies ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for your answer and explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `Series` to achieve this in `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

x = {0: {'a', 'b', 'c'},
1: {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
2: {'k', 'b', 'e', 'a', 'n'}}

lookup = pd.Series(x)
print(lookup[lookup.values == {'a', 'b', 'c'}])
# 0    {c, b, a}
# dtype: object
```

Comment: Is it scalable? And thanks for the approach! Can't understand why people downvoted your answer and my question...

Comment: I did not downvote the answer or the question, but I am pretty sure that this requires scanning through the entire Series each query.

Comment: Yes - this isn't a 'cached' approach, it's just a way to achieve this in `pandas` if that's a broader requirement of the task.