# How to have user true/false input in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python.

I want the program to ask

```
"is Johnny hungry? True or false?"
```

*user inputs True* 
  then print is `"Johnny needs to eat."`

*user inputs false*
  then print `"Johnny is full."`

I know to add an int I type in

```
johnnyHungry = int(input("Is johnny hungry "))
```

but I want them to enter True/false, not an int.

Comment: ... And what if the user inputs something other than "True" or "false"?

Comment: and why is one capitalized and one not?

Comment: this isn't totally comprehensive, but there is a handy lib for reading true false strings to booleans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715417/converting-from-a-string-to-boolean-in-python -- a yaml parser can also be used, Not sure I'd recommend that myself.

Answer (score 13):

you can use a simple helper that will force whatever input you want

```
def get_bool(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
           return {"true":True,"false":False}[input(prompt).lower()]
        except KeyError:
           print("Invalid input please enter True or False!")

print get_bool("Is Jonny Hungry?")
```

you can apply this to anything

```
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
           return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
           print("Thats not an integer silly!")
```

Comment: but then it can return something other than T/F ... I think OP wants the return to be forced (but I thought about something like that too :P good suggestion all the same)

Answer (score 11):

You can turn something *into* `True` or `False` using `bool`:

```
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool("True")
True
>>> bool("")
False
```

But there is a problem with a user entering "True" or "False" and assuming we can turn that `string` into a bool:

```
>>> bool("False")
True
```

This is because a `string` is considered *truthy* if it's not empty.

Typically, what we do instead is allow a user to enter a certain subset of possible inputs and then we tell the user that *only* these values are allowed if the user enters something else:

```
user_answer = input("Is johnny hungry ").lower().strip()
if user_answer == "true":
    # do something
elif user_answer == "false":
    # do something else
else:
    print("Error: Answer must be True or False")
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought yours was good as well but it could be a bit tough for a brand new Pythoner.

Comment: although it would probably be better to `if answer == "true":...elif answer == "false":... else:print "ERROR"`

Answer (score 2):

```
johnnyHungry = input("Is johnny hungry ")
if johnnyHungry == "True":
...
```

I expect that you can take it from there?

Comment: good answer for a python beginner even if it is not super robust :P +1

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_bool(prompt):
while True:
    try:
        return {"si": True, "no": False}[input(prompt).lower()]
    except KeyError:
        print ("Invalido ingresa por favor si o no!")

    respuesta = get_bool("Quieres correr este programa: si o no")

if (respuesta == True):
    x = 0
else:
    x = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code works for you. Because I already tried this code and it worked fine.

```
johnnyHungry = str(input("Is johnny hungry ")) 

def checking(x):
    return 'yes' == True
    return 'no' == False

if checking(johnnyHungry) == True:
    print("Johnny needs to eat.")
elif checking(johnnyHungry) == False:
    print("Johnny is full.")
```

I'm sorry if it's long, I'm new to programming either.

Comment: Actually newDelete's answer is not wrong and it's almost the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

***Code:***

```
question = str(input("Is Johnny hungry?  Response: "))

if question == "yes":

    print("Johnny needs to eat food!")

if question == "no":

    print("Johnny is full!")
```

***Run:***

1. Is Johnny hungry?    Response: yes

   Johnny needs to eat food!
2. Is Johnny hungry?    Response: no

   Johnny is full!
3. **This is if you type something other than yes and no**

   Is Johnny hungry?    Response: lkjdahkjehlhd

***Nothing pops up/ there is no response***

Answer (score -3):

You could just try bool(input("...")) but you would get into trouble if the user doesn't input a bool. You could just wrap it in a try statement.