# Python If-Statement always evaluates to true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Im very new to Python and decided I would try some basics.

Why does this always evaluate to true? Typing in "False" as UserInput should evaluate False?

```
true_or_false=input("Is it true or false?")
if true_or_false:
    print("It's true")
if not true_or_false:
    print("Well,it is not true")
```

Using newest Python Version (3.smth)

Comment: strings are always truthy (apart from empty strings)

Comment: Yup, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715417/converting-from-a-string-to-boolean-in-python), because `input` returns a string.

Comment: `true_or_false=ast.literal_eval(input("Is it true or false?").title())`

Answer (score 1):

The `if` condition evaluates the "truthiness" of the object passed to it:

```
if object:
    ...
```

Is the same as:

```
if bool(object):
    ...
```

You'll see any string of length greater than 0 has a truthiness value of `True`:

```
In [82]: bool('True')
Out[82]: True

In [83]: bool('False')
Out[83]: True
```

In essence, you'll need to change your `if` to:

```
if string == 'True':
    ...
elif string == 'False':
```

When using strings in comparisons, use the `==` operator unless you know what you're doing.

In addition, it is useful to know about the truthiness of some other python builtins:

```
In [84]: bool(None)
Out[84]: False

In [85]: bool({})
Out[85]: False

In [86]: bool([])
Out[86]: False

In [87]: bool(['a'])
Out[87]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

`true_or_false=input("Is it true or false?")`

will give the variable `true_or_false` a string value.

```
if true_or_false
```

will test if that's an empty string or not.

The solution is to compare the string to a string value:

```
if true_or_false == 'True'
```

If you want to guard against errors with upper- and lowercase letters you can do like this:

```
if true_or_false.lower() == 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in python always evaluate to `True` unless they are empty. You need to check if the string equals to `"True"`