# How to convert string int JSON into real int with json.loads

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

I'm trying to convert a string which represents a JSON object to a real JSON object using `json.loads` but it doesn't convert the integers:

(in the initial string, integers are always strings)

```
$> python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Aug 29 2016, 16:00:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> c = '{"value": "42"}'
>>> json_object = json.loads(c, parse_int=int)
>>> json_object
{u'value': u'42'}
>>> json_object['value']
u'42'
>>>
```

Instead of `{u'value': u'42'}` I'd like it becomes `{u'value': 42}`. I know I can run through the whole object, but I don't want to do that, it's not really efficient to do it manually, since this `parse_int` argument exists (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads).

Thanks to Pierce's proposition:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Aug 29 2016, 16:00:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>>
>>> class Decoder(json.JSONDecoder):
...     def decode(self, s):
...         result = super(Decoder, self).decode(s)
...         return self._decode(result)
...     def _decode(self, o):
...         if isinstance(o, str) or isinstance(o, unicode):
...             try:
...                 return int(o)
...             except ValueError:
...                 try:
...                     return float(o)
...                 except ValueError:
...                     return o
...         elif isinstance(o, dict):
...             return {k: self._decode(v) for k, v in o.items()}
...         elif isinstance(o, list):
...             return [self._decode(v) for v in o]
...         else:
...             return o
...
>>>
>>> c = '{"value": "42", "test": "lolol", "abc": "43.4",  "dcf": 12, "xdf": 12.4}'
>>> json.loads(c, cls=Decoder)
{u'test': u'lolol', u'dcf': 12, u'abc': 43.4, u'value': 42, u'xdf': 12.4}
```

Comment: Why is it `"42"` instead of `42` in the first place?

Comment: Well your JSON example `'{"value": "42"}'` has 42 as a string — not an int. Your best bet is either to fix the data coming in or (if that's not feasible) write a [custom JSON decoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: The `parse_int` option is only used for parts of the JSON that have the syntax of an integer. The double quotes make it a string, not an integer, so it doesn't use the `parse_int` option.

Comment: @Barmar I'm a bit lost on that functionality. From all JSON I've worked with, `42` would be an int without `parse_int` and `"42"` would be a string. Do you have a link for a use-case on `parse_int`?

Comment: What you really need is a `parse_str` option, which would allow you to supply a custom function that returns an `int` if the string contains a valid integer. Unfortunately, that option doesn't exist.

Comment: @roganjosh The documentation he linked to says "parse_int, if specified, will be called with the string of every JSON int to be decoded." So if the JSON contains `42`, the `parse_int` function will be called to parse it. But `"42"` is not a JSON int, so this option is not used for it.

Comment: @roganjosh The documentation suggests this use case: **This can be used to use another datatype or parser for JSON integers (e.g. float).**

Comment: @Barmar aha, I should have read further down. Your second comment clarifies, thanks.

Comment: First if clause content can be replaced with `json.loads(o)` insted of try excepts since this would work for all cases including "null", "true" and "false"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As we established in the comments, there is no existing functionality to do this for you. And I read through the documentation and some examples on the `JSONDecoder` and it also appears to not do what you want without processing the data twice.

The best option, then, is something like this:

```
class Decoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def decode(self, s):
        result = super().decode(s)  # result = super(Decoder, self).decode(s) for Python 2.x
        return self._decode(result)

    def _decode(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, str) or isinstance(o, unicode):
            try:
                return int(o)
            except ValueError:
                return o
        elif isinstance(o, dict):
            return {k: self._decode(v) for k, v in o.items()}
        elif isinstance(o, list):
            return [self._decode(v) for v in o]
        else:
            return o
```

This has the downside of processing the JSON object twice — once in the `super().decode(s)` call, and again to recurse through the entire structure to fix things. Also note that *this will convert anything which looks like an integer into an `int`*. Be sure to account for this appropriately.

To use it, you do e.g.:

```
>>> c = '{"value": "42"}'
>>> json.loads(c, cls=Decoder)
{'value': 42}
```

Comment: Thank you Pierce you code seems right but it has some errors on `result = super().decode(s)`

Comment: @Léo I wrote this in Python 3; if you're using Python 2 you'd need `result = super(Decoder, self).decode(s)`. If that's not the issue, can you tell me what error you're seeing and I can try to help you?

Comment: @Léo ah! I didn't realize it was doing unicode. I've updated my answer to accommodate the unicode handling, and it appears to work fine for me now!

Comment: Well. You saved my Day! Thx a lot. :)

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the Pierce response, I think you can use the json.loads `object_hook` parameter instead of `cls` one, so you don't need to walk the json object twice.

For example:

```
def _decode(o):
    # Note the "unicode" part is only for python2
    if isinstance(o, str) or isinstance(o, unicode):
        try:
            return int(o)
        except ValueError:
            return o
    elif isinstance(o, dict):
        return {k: _decode(v) for k, v in o.items()}
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        return [_decode(v) for v in o]
    else:
        return o

# Then you can do:
json.loads(c, object_hook=_decode)
```

As @ZhanwenChen pointed out in a comment, the code above is for [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads). For [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) you'll need to remove the `or isinstance(o, unicode)` part in the first `if` condition.

Comment: in [Python 3, the `str` class subsumed the `unicode` class](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support), so your code would raise because `unicode` is an undefined variable. Please edit your answer.

Comment: In the dict comp, if you might want to also decode the key you can use `{_decode(k): ...}`

Comment: `object_hook` will never be called if the string to be decoded contains no dict. For example `'["3"]'`. A hack would be to pass `f'{{"dummykey":{stringtodecode}}}` and return the first value of the decoded dict. Also I think returning `json.loads(o, object_hook=_decode)` and catching `json.JSONDecodeError` in the first if clause would cover the general type casting case

Answer (score 4):

For my solution I used `object_hook`, which is useful when you have nested `json`

```
>>> import json
>>> json_data = '{"1": "one", "2": {"-3": "minus three", "4": "four"}}'
>>> py_dict = json.loads(json_data, object_hook=lambda d: {int(k) if k.lstrip('-').isdigit() else k: v for k, v in d.items()})

>>> py_dict
{1: 'one', 2: {-3: 'minus three', 4: 'four'}}
```

There is a filter only for parsing a json key to int. You can use `int(v) if v.lstrip('-').isdigit() else v` to filter for json values too.

Comment: Excellent! It works like a charm. I wanted to transform str keys into int keys when possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @juanra and therefore @Pierce Darragh I added a conversion for boolean values from string. My example is a dict converted from XML that contains `'true'` and `'false'` that won't be loaded as JSON-boolean `True` and `False` automatically with the suggested answers.

```
def _decode(o):
    if isinstance(o, str):
        if o.lower() == 'true':
            return True
        elif o.lower() == 'false':
            return False
        else:
            try:
                return int(o)
            except ValueError:
                return o
    elif isinstance(o, dict):
        return {k: _decode(v) for k, v in o.items()}
    elif isinstance(o, list):
        return [_decode(v) for v in o]
    else:
        return o
```

According what you need you can also include other strings for boolean conversion with [Converting from a string to boolean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715417/converting-from-a-string-to-boolean-in-python)

Answer (score -3):

```
def convert_to_int(params):
    for key in params.keys():
        if isinstance(params[key], dict):
            convert_to_int(params[key])
        elif isinstance(params[key], list):
            for item in params[key]:
                if not isinstance(item, (dict, list)):
                    item = int(item)
                else:
                    convert_to_int(item)
        else:
            params[key] = int(params[key])
    return params


print convert_to_int({'a': '3', 'b': {'c': '4', 'd': {'e': 5}, 'f': [{'g': '6'}]}})
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the OP wanted to parse the value `"42"` into an `int` in Python, which your code does not account for.

Comment: convert = lambda x: {x.keys()[0]: int(x.values()[0])} convert(json.loads('{"value": "42"}'))

Comment: Your lambda suggestion only works for dictionaries with exactly one value. It does not solve for multi-value dictionaries or arrays, and it also does not address the Unicode problem present in Python 2. Further, it isn't advisable to set the result of a `lambda` expression to a variable; just define a function and it becomes significantly easier to maintain. See my (accepted) answer for a more robust solution.

Comment: how about this one?

Comment: Better, but `for key in params.keys()` assumes that `params` is a `dict`, which it may not be since you call the function recursively. Additionally, you iterate through the keys of the dictionary and then continuously do `params[key]`. Why not `for key, value in params.items()` (or `params.iteritems()` in Python 2.x)? Additionally, much of this can be done with comprehensions — like what I did in my solution. I think list/dict comprehensions lead to easier-to-read code in cases like this.