# How do I get a boolean value from an input?

Tags: python, boolean

I want to ask the user a true/false question and get a boolean value from it, but I don't really understand how `.bool()` works. This is more of a "what can I do?' than a "what's the problem?".

So for example, this is what my code is looking like:

```
question = input("Is the Earth flat? ")
if question.bool() is True:
     print("You dumb.")
```

I know this isn't correct but I'm not sure what would work!

What makes the `.bool()` register True or False?

I thought this might be what I have to do but it doesn't seem right:

```
if question == "Yes" or "Yeah" or "Y" or "Duh".lower()
     print("You dumb.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in` for this, not multiple `or` statements as it’s less readable in its correct form and less efficient. Also `sets` are great for checking inclusivity.

```
question = input("Is the Earth flat? ")
if question.lower() in {"yes", "yeah", "y", "duh"}:
     print("You dumb.")
```

You could even make a custom function to ask a question and return a Boolean result

```
def ask_bool(question):
    return input(question).lower() in {"yes", "yeah", "y", "duh"}
```

Then to ask for a Boolean answer:

```
if ask_bool("Is the Earth flat? "):
     print("You dumb.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `element in list:`

```
if question.lower() in ["yes", "yeah", "y", "duh"]:
     print("You dumb.")
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second option, this does not work because python doesn't understand what the other conditions are. The correct way to check multiple conditions for equality is the following

```
if (question == "Yes" or question == "Yeah" or question == "Y" or question == "Duh".lower())
     print("You dumb.")
```

However, this is probably not the best way to do this with this many terms, and you're better off storing them in a list and iterating through.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend to use elements in list: between the [] you just have to list all the possible answers that you can accept and process.

```
if question.lower() in ["Yes", "YES", "true", "TRUE"]:
     print("You dumb!")
else:
     print("You are not stupid!")
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution with default yes answer

```py
ans = input("Your answer [Y/n]: ")

if ans.lower() == "n":
    # nooooo 
else:
    # yessss
```

However you should see this too, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48817835/10362396

Answer (score 0):

```
question = input("Is the Earth flat? ")

if question.lower() == "Yes".lower() or question.lower() == "Yeah".lower():
  print(question)
  print("You dumb.")
```