# How to get a Boolean input from the user in python?

Tags: python, input, boolean

I want to get an input from user. If I want a string as an input, then I can have `input("enter your answer")`
But if I want the input as a boolean value: True or False ONLY, how can I do it in python?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48817562/9472529)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

- Create a separate method that asks for input of strings like `"True"` or `"False"` and that use that method as a boolean according to what it returns:

> ```py
>        def trueCheck():
>         response = input("True or False?")
>         if response == "True":
>             return True
>         if response == "False":
>             return False
> ```

- Or pass the response from `_main` to the method and return a boolean:

> ```py
>        def trueCheck(response):
>         if response == "True":
>             return True
>         if response == "False":
>             return False
> ```