# python script fall in infinite while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I want my script to repeat `input` question until the user prompt the right answer. After the user prompted the right answer, the script has to go on with the relative if statement  In this case `hostname` or `file`.  I came out with the below code, however seems to fall into infinite loop.

```
import socket

def ipFromHost():
  opt1 = input('Do you want provide  hostname or file: ') 
  while opt1 != 'hostname' or 'file':
    input('Please, type "hostname" or "file"')
  if opt1 == 'hostname':
    optHostname = input('Please, provide hostname: ')
    print(socket.gethostbyname(optHostname.strip()))
  elif opt1 == 'file':
    optFile = input('Please, provide file name: ')
    with open(optFile) as inputFile:
      for i in inputFile:
        print(socket.gethostbyname(i.strip()))
```

Thanks!

Comment: `while opt1 != 'hostname' or 'file':` is not doing what you think it is...

Comment: `while opt1 != 'hostname' or 'file':`
This is interpretead as : While opt1 != 'hostname' or 'file' == true

Or, 'file' == true
In fact, every other thing than 0 is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because the condition `while opt1 != 'hostname' or 'file':` checks 2 conditions:

1. `opt1 != 'hostname'` OR
2. `'file'`

even if `opt1 != 'hostname'` will evaluate to `True`, the second condition actually checks if `'file'` is `True` or `False` (compare `if opt1 != 'file'` to `if 'file'`). *You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715417/converting-from-a-string-to-boolean-in-python) answer about Boolean value of strings in python*

Since `if 'file'` is always `True` you gen an infinite loop

Fix with

1. `while opt1 != 'hostname' and opt1 != 'file':` *[using `AND` since `opt1` must be different from both options]* OR
2. `while opt1 not in ('hostname', 'file')` *[which seems neater in my opnion]*

---

Your code should look something like this:

```
def ipFromHost():
  opt1 = input('Do you want provide  hostname or file: ') 
  while opt1 not in ('hostname', 'file'):
    opt1 = input('Please, type "hostname" or "file"')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. I can see now the loop is "fixed" however script in not able to move on if statement after prompt hostname or file

`>>> ipFromHost()

Do you want provide  hostname or file: home

Please, type "hostname" or "file": home

Please, type "hostname" or "file": file

Please, type "hostname" or "file": hostname

Please, type "hostname" or "file": 
`

Comment: @FedericoOlivieri see my answer: your code does not update the value of opt1 with the user input.

Comment: @tehhowch I don't understand what you mean. Could you please provide an example to how fix it so I can maybe understand. Thanks!

Comment: @FedericoOlivieri -  as @tehhowch said, while inside the loop, you ask for `input()` but you don't assign the result into `opt1`

Comment: @FedericoOlivieri I did provide an example. See the other answer to your question, and compare the two lines I wrote with the relevant lines you originally wrote.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have got it now. It works as expected. Thanyou for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
while opt1 not in ["hostname", "file"]:
    opt1 = input(...
```

As mentioned in comments, your while loop has bad conditions.

Comment: A tuple (instead of a list) is more performant and better reflects the immutability of the comparison values.