# Mapping boolean string values to true/false in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I'm converting a CSV file into JSON like this:

```
import os
import csv
import json

with open(args.infile, encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
  csv_rows = list(csv.DictReader(csv_file))

with open(args.outfile, "w", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
  json.dump(csv_rows, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

The CSV file contains a column which can have the values `"true"` and `"false"` as strings. These shall be mapped to the JSON as `true` and `false` (**not** in the Python style of `True` or `False`).

Is there a built-in function which I can use?

Comment: bool(distutils.util.strtobool(some_string)) Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715417/converting-from-a-string-to-boolean-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting from a string to boolean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715417/converting-from-a-string-to-boolean-in-python)

Comment: As far as I can see this converts the string to Python's `True` or `False`. These values however are not valid in JSON where it must be `true` or `false`?

Comment: Note that: When you output the value `True` with json-library's dump function it is automatically converted to `true` (javascript-syntax). This is the purpose of the library!

Comment: I **don't** think this is a duplicate of [Converting from a string to boolean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715417/converting-from-a-string-to-boolean-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do it would be to preprocess each row of the csv file before passing it to `json.dump()` to map strings with those names in them to Python booleans—which the `json.dump()` will change into the type of JSON boolean values you desire. This is what I mean:

```
import os
import csv
import json

with open(args.infile, newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_rows = [[True if row[field] == 'true' else
                 False if row[field] == 'false' else
                 row[field] for field in row] for row in csv.DictReader(csv_file)]

with open(args.outfile, "w", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
    json.dump(csv_rows, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Sample CSV input:

```
Field Name1,Field Name2,Field Name3,Field Name4,Field Name5
1,2,true,3,4
5,6,false,7,8
9,10,non-bool,11,12
```

Sample JSON output:

```
[
  [
    "1",
    "2",
    true,
    "3",
    "4"
  ],
  [
    "5",
    "6",
    false,
    "7",
    "8"
  ],
  [
    "9",
    "10",
    "non-bool",
    "11",
    "12"
  ]
]
```