# My if statement not working in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make a random sentence generator, and this piece of code should make the program use "an" when `noun2` begins with a vowel.

```
import random
noun=['it', 'he', 'she', 'I']
verb=['am', 'is', 'are' ]
noun1=random.choice(noun).capitalize()+" "
verb1=random.choice(verb)+" "
noun2=random.choice(noun)+"."
if noun2[:1]=='a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':
    asentence=noun1+verb1+'an '+noun2
    print(asentence)
else:
  print('hi')
```

But when I run the program, it always uses "an" even when `noun2` starts with a consonant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python works differently from the english language.

`if noun2[:1]=='a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u':` should be

```
if noun2[:1]=='a' or noun2[:1]=='e' or noun2[:1]=='i' or noun2[:1]=='o' or noun2[:1]=='u':
```

Something like this would be a better way to do it `if noun2[:1] in 'aeiou':`

This question has been previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true). You can read more about logical OR [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

Comment: What does if noun2[:1]=='a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u': do?

Comment: @F.M It will always give `True` because all strings (except empty strings) evaluate to True if used as boolean conditions. The above line reads `if "e" or if "i" or if "o"` etc. and they are all `True`. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715417/converting-from-a-string-to-boolean-in-python