# Why is .astype('bool') converting all values to True?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a column in a dataframe of strings 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' to a boolean. For other data types I've simply used astype and not had any issues, but for some reason using it on this column converts all the values to True.

I have repeated the test on a list of strings as follows

```
test = ['False','False','True']
test = pd.DataFrame(test)
test = test.astype('bool')
```

But it gives the same result, what is going on here and how do I properly convert the datatype? I've tried using map and replace to change the values before conversion but neither changed the outcome.

Comment: Your values in list are strings not boolean.

Comment: Your list contains strings, and string converts to `False` only when it is empty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is problem [strings values are converted to Trues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/715455).

Solution:

```
test = ['False','False','True']
test = pd.DataFrame(test)
test = test[0].map({'False':False, 'True':True})
print (test)
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Or:

```
import ast

test = test[0].map(ast.literal_eval)
print (test)
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

one clear approach do this will be,

```
test=test[0]=='True'
```

O/P:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
bool
```