# pydantic string 'false' to bool

Tags: python, boolean, pydantic

I have pydantic model like

```
class AccountingQueueFilters(BaseModel):
    no_batch_id: Optional[bool] = None
```

but for input `'false'` from get params it return `True`

https://mysite.tech/accounting_queue/get?no_batch_id=false

How to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this construction
It will allow you to access properties via dot notation and make custom type checks

```
class QueryParams:
    def make_bool(self, value):
        return not(value == "false")  # some logic

    def __init__(self, boolable: str, zero: bool):
        self.boolable = self.make_bool(boolable)
        self.zero = zero


@router.get('/route')
async def route(
        data: QueryParams = Depends(),
):
    print(data) # boolable=false : str
    print(type(data.boolable))  # bool
    print("success")
    return Result(data)
```

Comment: It seems to me this does not answer the question: "pydantic string 'false' to bool". The correct answer should be https://stackoverflow.com/a/71510434/2173868